# Spring boot - One-to-one relationship not reflected on both tables after updating one entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I have two entities Employee and Review. I am trying to create a OneToOne relationship Employee <-> Review.

When I update an Employee with a review, the Employee gets updated where the review becomes the corresponding review,
but the Review doesn't get the 'reviewee' column added with the ID of the employee which is what I expect.

What am I doing wrong?

These are my entities:

```
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reviewee")
    private Review review;
}

public class Review {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String body;
    private char completed;


   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "review")
   private Employee reviewee;
}
```

This is my employeeController update function:

```
@GetMapping(path="/update") 
    public @ResponseBody Employee updateEmployee (@RequestParam Integer id,
             @RequestParam(value = "name", required=false) String name,
             @RequestParam(value = "email", required=false) String email,
             @RequestParam() Integer reviewId) {

        Employee n = EmployeeRepository.findOne(id);

        if(name == null) {
            name = n.getName();
        }

        if(email == null) {
            email = n.getEmail();
        }

        n.setName(name);
        n.setEmail(email);

        Review r =  ReviewRepository.findOne(reviewId);

        n.setReview(r);
        EmployeeRepository.save(n);
        return n;
    }
```

The request:

```
curl 'localhost:8080/employees/update?id=2&reviewId=1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the owner of the relationship (the one with `@JoinColumn`) is `Employee`, you have to create/update/delete the association by saving the `Employee` object.

This is what you are doing so far. But Hibernate will only update the owner when you save it. You should in addition do this before returning your entity:

```
r.setReviewee(n);
```

Notice that the next time you will retrieve the review, it will correctly have an `Employee` object.

Beware: I smell a Jackson infinite loop there when serializing.

```
Employee.review -> Review -> Review.reviewee -> Employee -> Employee.review...
```

**EDIT**

To prevent the Jackson infinite loop:

**1.** Ignore the serialization.

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {

    // ...

    // Do not serialize this field
    @JsonIgnore

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reviewee")
    private Review review;

    // ...
}
```

**2.** Serialize as ID.

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {

    // ...

    // Serialize as a single value with the field "id"
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")

    // Serialize as told by @JsonIdentityInfo immediately (if false -> on second and further occurrences)
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)

    // Rename to "review_id" (would be "review" otherwise)
    @JsonProperty(value = "review_id")

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reviewee")
    private Review review;

    // ...
}
```

**3.** Alternative to serialize as ID: read-only reference to the foreign key.

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {

    // ...

    // Do not serialize this field
    @JsonIgnore

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reviewee")
    private Review review;

    // Read-only access to the foreign key
    @Column(name = "Review_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer reviewId;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I feel like there is going to be an infinity loop. How can I avoid that if I want each entity to relate to each other?

Comment: @criver.to See the **EDIT** section of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be a configuration mismatch. Please try the below one.

```
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="reviewee",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Review review; }

public class Review {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")    
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters={@Parameter(name="property",value="reviewee")})
    private Integer id;
    private String body;
    private char completed;

   @OneToOne    
   @PrimaryKeJoinCloumn    
   private Employee reviewee; }
```

I hope the above configuration works as you expected.

Please make sure you're calling the save function under Transaction boundary. Otherwise don't forget to call flush() before closing the session.